# Prev_permutation vs Next_permutation difficulty

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, permutation, probability

I was trying out a sample program to grasp the difference between prev and next permutation. However, my program doesn't seem to work properly. I start the program by asking the number of elements in the array and I build the array with a simple for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        ptr[i] = i;

cout << "Possible permuations using prev_permutation: " << endl;
    do{
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
            cout << ptr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    } while(prev_permutation(ptr, ptr+x));

cout << "Possible permuations using next_permutation: " << endl;
do{
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
} while(next_permutation(ptr, ptr+x));
```

When I run the code with a sample of 3 elements, (0, 1, 2). The prev_permutation gives me (0, 1, 2 and thats it). Then next_permutation gives me (2, 1, 0). However, when I comment the code for the prev_permutation part, I get a proper 6 different permutations of the set (0, 1, 2) when only next_permutation is running. I can't seem to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`prev_permutation` and `next_permutation` generate all permutations in lexicographical ("alphabetical") order and they return `false` once the cycle has been completed (i.e. if after calling `prev_permutation` on the first permutation or after calling `next_permutation` on the last one).

What happens is that you prepare the array with the first permutation in lexicographical order, then you call `prev_permutation`. This is however the first, so `prev_permutation` sets the array to the last permutation and the returns `false`, so you exit the loop.

Now you enter the `next_permutation` loop, but the current content of the array is the last permutation in lexicographical order, so `next_permutation` will set the first one and will return false.

If you remove the `prev_permutation` part however the loop for `next_permutation` will start from the first and so it will generate correctly all 6 permutations before returning `false`.

You can visualize the effect considering all permutations listed in order and with the current configuration as a pointer in this list:

```
0-1-2 << you start here
0-2-1
1-0-2
1-2-0
2-0-1
2-1-0
```

when calling `next_permutation` you are moving down, when calling `prev_permutation` you are moving up. When going outside the list both function will move the pointer to the other end and will return `false` to inform you of this fact.

If you start with `prev` you move to `2-1-0` and function returns `false`, then you call `next` and the function move to `0-1-2` and returns `false` again.

Using for example instead of `0`, `1` and `2` the permutations of two zeros and three ones the lexicographical ordering is:

```
0-0-1-1-1
0-1-0-1-1
0-1-1-0-1
0-1-1-1-0
1-0-0-1-1
1-0-1-0-1
1-0-1-1-0
1-1-0-0-1
1-1-0-1-0
1-1-1-0-0
```

So to enumerate all of them you need to start from `0-0-1-1-1` and use `next_permutation` or you need to start from `1-1-1-0-0` and use `prev_permutation`.

In this case calling `next_permutation` on the last one `1-1-1-0-0` will change to the first `0-0-1-1-1` and will return `false`; in a similar way calling `prev_permutation` on `0-0-1-1-1` will change to `1-1-1-0-0` and will return `false` because of the flip.

Comment: I had one quick question. When you say, the list being ordered lexicographically, does it mean by value? So for example, I ran another example of prev_permutation with the input (1 1 1 0 0). After I ran this, I got all the possible permutations, but I don't understand how do prev and next determine what the next permutation will be. Thanks.

Comment: Lexicographical order means that to decide if a sequence is before or after another you start by first comparing first element, if it's different then the first element decides the ordering... if it's equal in both then you move to second element and so on. Among the permutations of three ones and two zeros the permutation `(1 1 1 0 0)`  is the last in lexicographical order, so you can cycle through all permutations using `prev_permutations` from there. The first one is instead `(0 0 1 1 1)` and you can cycle over all permutations using `next_permutation` starting from it.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up! would it be possible to run a set of (0 0 0 1 1) by next_permutation and then get the FINAL result and run the prev_permutation to get back 0 0 0 1 1? So, if I store the values in an array, does this function change the values of the array.

Answer (score 3):

All the permutations considered by both `prev_permutation` and `next_permutation` have a well-defined **lexicographical order**.  The array you provided to them has some position in that order.

That's why neither function is guaranteed to provide all permutations.

If you provide the first possible permutation to `prev_permutation`, which you did, there will be no permutations before it.  Likewise, if your array were defined as (2, 1, 0), `next_permutation` would not provide any new permutations.

**If you need all the permutations of some collection, you would want to `sort` the collection first and then use `next_permutation`.**